# Help to understand the generalization of the Argument Principle

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading Conway's complex analysis book and I'm trying to prove this theorem left to the reader on page 124:

[image]

I tried to use integration by parts without success. I need some hint how prove this theorem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can proceed similarly as in the proof of the "ordinary" argument
principle. Write
$$
 f(z) = \frac{\prod_{j=1}^n (z-z_j)}{\prod_{k=1}^m (z-p_k)} h(z)
$$
where $h$ is holomorphic and $\ne 0$ in $G$. Now take the logarithmic
derivative
$$
 \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{z-z_j} - \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{z-p_k} + \frac{h'(z)}{h(z)}
$$
and multiply with $g(z)$
$$
 g(z) \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{g(z)}{z-z_j} - \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{g(z)}{z-p_k} + g(z) \frac{h'(z)}{h(z)} \\
 = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{g(z_j)}{z-z_j} - \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{g(p_k)}{z-p_k} + \left( g(z) \frac{h'(z)}{h(z)} + \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{g(z)-g(z_j)}{z-z_j} - \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{g(z)-g(p_k)}{z-p_k} \right) \, .
$$
The term in parentheses has only removable singularities in $G$, therefore
$$ \tag{*}
g(z) \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{g(z_j)}{z-z_j} - \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{g(p_k)}{z-p_k} + \phi(z)
$$
with an holomorphic function $\phi$ in $G$.

The assertion now follows since for $a =z_1, \ldots, z_n, p_1, \ldots, p_m$
$$
 \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma  \frac{g(a)}{z-a}\, dz = g(a) \operatorname{n}(\gamma; a)
$$ and
$$
 \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \phi(z) \, dz = 0
$$
due to the Cauchy integral theorem.

*Remark:* Another method to obtain $(*)$ would be to observe that both
$$
g(z) \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} 
$$
and
$$ \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{g(z_j)}{z-z_j} - \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{g(p_k)}{z-p_k} 
$$
are holomorphic in $A$ with the only exception of (at most) simple poles
at the zeros and poles of $f$, and that the principle parts at those
points are the same. Therefore the difference has only removable
singularities.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I didn't understand just one thing. Why is $\phi$ an holomorphic function? the term in parentheses may have removable singularities, right?

Comment: @user42912: A function has a [removable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity) at a point $a$ if it can be defined in the point $a$ in such a way that the continuation is holomorphic in $a$ as well. In this case, [Riemann's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem) tells us that the term in parentheses can be continued holomorphically to the entire domain $A$ (because it is *bounded* in the neighborhood of each $z_j$ and $p_k$).

Comment: Yes, i understand that if $a$ is a removable singularity, then you can redefine $\phi(a)$ such that $\phi$ is holomorphic. The problem is when you redefine $\phi (a)$ you change the function represented by the parentheses terms at this point and we don't have an equality anymore. I hope you have understood my doubt. Thank you again.

Comment: @user42912: You still have the equality in $G$ minus the $z_j$ and $p_k$. And that is sufficient to compute the integral because $\gamma$ avoids these points.

Comment: Yes, of course. You answer is perfectly clear to me now. Thank you again!

Comment: May I ask why you have to write $g(z)=(g(z)-g(z_i))+g(z_i)$ ? Since we already have the analyticity of $g$ and also the cauchy integral formula

Comment: @mnmn1993: The above proof (if I remember correctly) uses only the Cauchy integral theorem and the definition of the winding number. If you assume the Cauchy integral formula as known then you can omit one step.

Comment: Anyone knows why is needed the hypothesis that $G$ is a region? In the original statement of the Principle argument $G$ can be any open set of $\mathbb{C}$, right? Thanks in advance

Comment: @AleTolcachier: It is not needed, $G$ can be an arbitrary open set. It is *assumed* that $\gamma$ is homologous to zero in $G$ ($\gamma \approx 0$), so that $ \int_\gamma \phi(z) \, dz = 0$. – If $G$ is a simply-connected domain then $\gamma \approx 0$ is automatically satisfied.

Comment: @MartinR in the initial logarithmic derivative, the numerators are all 1. how is this possible? whenever i take the logarithmic derivative, i end up with a constant. when you're multiplying the zeros and poles, don't you need to include the multiplicities and orders as exponents?

Comment: @ekorel: The numerators are equal to one because multiple zeros or poles are repeated in $z_1, \ldots, z_n$ and $p_1, \ldots, p_m$ according to their multiplicities. Example: If $f$ has a triple zero at $z=a$ then three of the $z_j$ are equal to $a$, so the total contribution to the logarithmic derivative is $3 \cdot \frac{1}{z-a}$.

Comment: @MartinR so are the terms (z-a)^n being split into (z-a)(z-a)...(z-a) in your initial f(z) before you take the derivative? that way you end up only with powers of 1, and 1 as a coefficient?

Comment: @ekorel: Yes, exactly.

Comment: @MartinR just so you have an idea of where my confusion is, in the book that I'm reading through, the logarithmic derivative is written out like [this](https://imgur.com/a/mctCJYS), so I'm just confused as to where all of those constants in the numerator went, because when I go to do the Cauchy integral formula on the sums of the integrals (g(z)/(z-z^k)), they're still there.


edit: oh, alright then. i had no clue that was possible, it felt like cheating! thank you for answering.