# $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma z^m\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=\sum_k (z_k)^m$

Tags: complex-analysis

This question comes from Joseph Bak Complex Analysis.
Suppose f is analytic inside and on a regular closed curve γ and has no zeroes on γ . Show that if m
is a positive integer then $ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma z^m \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=\sum_k (z_k)^m $,
where the sum is taken over the zeroes of f inside $\gamma$.
I can't realy use the claim that it's the number of zeores of $z^m f$ , and I can't see how it follow from the residue thm. Any hint will be great!

Comment: That is a consequence of the “generalized argument principle,” see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1803460/42969.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows from the [generalized argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle#Generalized_argument_principle) that$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma z^m\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=\sum_{z_k\in Z} (z_k)^m\eta(\gamma,z_k)-\sum_{w_k\in P} (w_k)^m\eta(\gamma,w_k),$$where $Z$ is the set of zeros of $f$ and $P$ is the set of its poles. But there are no poles here and all those winding numbers $\eta(\gamma,z_k)$ are equal to $1$.